# Meteor -> percolatestudio/meteor-migrations --- not working for version 0

Tags: meteor, migration

Trying to get this migrations plugin working for meteor project: percolatestudio/meteor-migrations

Migrating up and down between various migration versions seems to work fine when greater than 0.
However when trying to migrate back to 0 (clean slate), it doesn't seem to work. Nothing happens --- no errors, and it still thinks it is at the last version it migrated to.

Here is my code for a simple migration:

```
Migrations.add({
  version: 1,
  name: 'Add engagement and lastActiveAt fields to cloud users for analytics',

  up: function() {
        CloudUsers.update({}, { $set: { lastActiveAt: Date.now(), engagements: {} } }, { multi: true });
  },

  down: function() {
          CloudUsers.update({}, { $unset: { lastActiveAt: '',  engagements: '' } }, { multi: true });
  }
});
```

It successfully migrates up(), but will not migrate back down() to 0. However if I copy & paste this code and create a version 2 migration. I can successfully migrate up and down between the two.

I am following the documentation on how to revert back to version 0:

```
Migrations.migrateTo(0)
```

Comment: What is the behavior if you run this `Migrations.migrateTo(0);` ?

Comment: Behavior is the same as I described above....thats the command I ran to attempt to get it back to 0.

Comment: I have a feeling that there might be a problem with the package itself....which is surprising because percolatesstudio usually produces solid stuff :/

Comment: Its not a huge deal, I just would like to get it to work if possible. The package itself is still really useful and it works like expected everywhere else (just not when getting back to version 0). One slightly hacky workaround is to have "version 1" just be an empty up() an down() setup so that reverting back to state 1 would effectively be the same as migrating back to 0.

Comment: I would suggest to ask on their [github repo](https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-migrations/issues).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug with that specific version, the latest version now has fixed this issue.